# Making any letter in () a lower case all other letters uppercase

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a variable string uppercase and letters that are within () lower case. string will be what ever the user enters so do not know what it will be ahead of time.

user entry examples

What is entered

(H)e(L)lo
what is expected outcome

(h)E(l)LO
What is entered

(H)ELLO (W)orld
what is expected outcome

(h)ELLO (w)ORLD
here is what i have tried but can only get it to work if the () are at the end of the string.

```
if(getElementById("ID")){
    var headline = getElementById("ID").getValue();
    var headlineUpper = headline.toUpperCase();
    var IndexOf = headlineUpper.indexOf("(");
    if(IndexOf === -1){
        template.getRegionNode("Region").setValue(headlineUpper);
    }
    else{
        var plus = parseInt(IndexOf + 1);
        var replacing = headlineUpper[plus];
        var lower = replacing.toLowerCase();
        var render = headlineUpper.replace(headlineUpper.substring(plus), lower + ")");
        
        getElementById("Region").setValue(render);
    }
}
```

Do to our system i am only able to use vanilla javascript. i have asked a similar question before with one () but now we are expecting more then one () in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Using_an_inline_function_that_modifies_the_matched_characters) method with a regular expression. First you can make your string all uppercase using `.toUpperCase()`. Then, you can match all characters in-between `(` and `)` and use the replacement function of the `replace` method to convert the matched characters to lowercase.

See example below:

```js
function uppercase(str) {
  return str.toUpperCase().replace(/\(.*?\)/g, function(m) {
    return m.toLowerCase();
  });
}

console.log(uppercase("(H)e(L)lo")); // (h)E(l)LO
console.log(uppercase("(H)ELLO (W)orld")); // (h)ELLO (w)ORLD
```

If you can support ES6 you can clean up the above function with arrow functions:

```js
const uppercase = str => 
    str.toUpperCase().replace(/\(.*?\)/g, m => m.toLowerCase());

console.log(uppercase("(H)e(L)lo")); // (h)E(l)LO
console.log(uppercase("(H)ELLO (W)orld")); // (h)ELLO (w)ORLD
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want a faster regex alternative, you can use a negated character (`^)`) regex instead of laziness (`?`). It's faster as it [doesn't require backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

```
const uppercase = str => 
    str.toUpperCase().replace(/\([^)]+\)/g, m => m.toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it without use of any regex. I'm storing the indexes of all `(` and `)`.

```js
String.prototype.replaceBetween = function (start, end, what) {
    return this.substring(0, start) + what + this.substring(end);
};

function changeCase(str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();

    let startIndex = str.split('').map((el, index) => (el === '(') ? index : null).filter(el => el !== null);
    let endIndex = str.split('').map((el, index) => (el === ')') ? index : null).filter(el => el !== null);

    Array.from(Array(startIndex.length + 1).keys()).forEach(index => {
        if (index !== startIndex.length) {
            let indsideParentheses = '(' + str.substring(startIndex[index] + 1, endIndex[index]).toUpperCase() + ')';
            str = str.replaceBetween(startIndex[index], endIndex[index] + 1, indsideParentheses);
        }
    });

    return str;
}

let str = '(h)ELLO (w)ORLD'
console.log(changeCase(str));
```